# LDAP Search wildcard not working

Tags: python, ldap, ldap-client

I am trying to search my LDAP directory and I am unable to search with substring filters when the value is a set of attributes and values.

Scenario:
In my python script, I am able to search the LDAP server. Therefore, I will omit code regarding the connection, DN configuration amongst others and focus on the `Filter`.

**Filter1: (works)**

> '(&(objectClass=person)(managedObjects=CN=SKSOBHEE-MOBL,OU=Mobile,OU=Production,OU=Windows
>   7,OU=IT
>   Client,OU=Resources,DC=emea,DC=xx,DC=yy,DC=com)(objectClass=organizationalPerson)(objectClass=user))'

**Filter2: (fails)**

> '(&(objectClass=person)(managedObjects=CN=SKSOBHEE-MOBL*)(objectClass=organizationalPerson)(objectClass=user))'

Searching with *Filter1* returns a user but fails with *Filter2* when I use the substring.

Searching is done using:

> l.search_s(BASE_DN, SCOPE, Filter1, Attrs)

I would appreciate some help on this!

Thank you.

Comment: It is "substring", not "wildcard". LDAP filters do not use wildcards. Does `managedObjects` have a substring matching rule? Most DN syntax attributes do not use a substring rule when matching DNs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. How can I know if an attribute has a matching rule? I am using `LDAP Admin for Windows` to visually see the tree.

Comment: The attribute syntax definition for `managedObjects` should contain the attribute syntax and all the matching and ordering rules. If there is no substring matching rule, then substrings will not work in the filter.

Comment: Using LDAP Admin's Schema Viewer, I have details about the `managedObjects` attribute. Link: http://s14.postimg.org/utfu3swip/pscreen.png . I see that the `Substring` subattribute is empty. Is that the reason why I cannot use wildcards?

Comment: If I am understanding that image, yes is the answer to your question. For equality filters, there must be an equality match, for substring filters, a substring match, etc. In this case, it's `substring`.

Comment: This question should not be put on hold: the answer is an important piece of LDAP daily working knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **wildcard**, use **substring** instead when asking about these types of filters.

When a `substring` filter is used, a `substring` matching rule must be defined for the attribute used in the filter. For `equality` filters, there must be an `equality` match, for `substring` filters, a  `substring` match, etc.

Here is an example of an attribute definition of `name` with an equality and a substring rule:

```
attributeTypes: ( 2.5.4.41 NAME 'name' EQUALITY caseIgnoreMatch
  SUBSTR caseIgnoreSubstringsMatch SYNTAX 1.3.6.1.4.1.1466.115.121.1.15{32768}
  X-ORIGIN 'RFC 4519' )
```

If a matching rule is not included for the type of filter, the search won't work as you might think.

#### see also

- [LDAP: Mastering Search Filters](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/mastering-ldap-search-filters.html)
- [LDAP: Search best practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)